# Why use NestJS createMicroservice over NestFactory.create?

Tags: javascript, typescript, architecture, nestjs, microservices

in my team we use NestJS for our backend. We want to use microservices architecture and I've seen there is a built-in microservices support in NestJS. After read the documentation I've got a few questions about this feature:

1. Should I create microservices in the same project or in separate projects?
2. Why even use `createMicroservice` over `NestFactory.create`? Using `createMicroservice` also makes me to use `@MessagePattern` and use an emitter to send messages - which is okay if my microservice gets messages using queue (like RabbitMQ), but I can't create REST API in my microservice, so it makes it harder (or impossible) to call NestJS microservice from non-NestJS microservice since it relies on NestJS `MessagePattern`.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is not necessary but I personally create separate projects within a workspace.
2. Calling `createMicroservice` is compulsory because nest needs to know what kind of controller you have and what behavior do you expect. In addition, you should avoid implementing rest API in all services; it should be implemented just in gateway service which is responsible for API layer, and it is a bond between microservices and outworld.

For having a good notion about microservice implementation with NestJS I highly recommend you to take a look to this repo:
https://github.com/Denrox/nestjs-microservices-example

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Why should I avoid using REST API in all services? BTW - I don't REST in all my microservices, but isn't it more suitable for some use cases? In addition - if  use microservices from multiple technologies - for example Spring, will it be possible to send a message from Spring microservice to NestJS microservice?

Comment: Just to be clear - some of my microservices will be communicated via RabbitMQ, but there are several microservices that doesn't need to be RabbitMQ consumers, for those microservices I've thought the REST API is more suitable

Comment: That's how this guys build Nest JS BTW you can use custom transporters but I don't recommend it. You can send message to any service which supports the protocol used in nest. Don't use http for making communication between services; it is slow in contrast with Nats or Redis pub/sub. I suggest you to use Nats, always my first choice, due to its high performance and queue groups.